# How to type adb shell commands in one line?

Tags: android, shell, unix, cmd, adb

I want to type multiple adb shell commands in one line,
 for example, i want to type `adb shell` and `su` and  `cd sys` together. i tried to connect them with `&&` and `&` 
 bzw.`adb shell && su && cd sys`,
 but it seems like not work with adb commands, but works with windows commands. 
does anybody knows what is the problem?

Comment: which os you are using

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @simmant  my OS is Win 7

Comment: @PareshMayani sorry, i will change the tags

Answer (score 6):

Sovled by myself `adb shell "su -c 'cd sys'"`

Comment: How about inserting an argument, ie $2, into the command executed inside the shell. For instance cd $2. How can I do that?

Comment: (UP) Nice and thanks!